# Unable to remove dynamically added content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I'm using jQuery to let users dynamically add and remove form fields, but it's not working properly.

It works perfectly fine when removing the first field (which is hard-coded in the HTML mark-up), but it won't let me remove any of the fields that have been added dynamically.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$("#addDog").click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var doglist = <?php echo "'" . $javadogs . "'"; ?>;
    var newdog = '<div><select name="resDog[]" class="select">' + doglist + '</select><input type="text" class="shortinput" name="resResult[]" size="20" value="" /><a href="#" class="deleteDog"><img src="/admin/images/delete.png" alt="Remove dog" /></a></div>';
    $(this).parent().before(newdog);
});

$(".deleteDog").click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I tried using jQuery's `.on()` function, but that didn't work either.

Comment: What did your `$.on()` look like? It's syntax is slightly different than `$.live()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how you want to use `on`

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteDog", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Ideally all of these `deleteDog` buttons will be housed in some sort of container.  If all of these buttons were to be in a div with an id of `foo`, you would more efficiently set up the events like this:

```
$("#foo").on("click", ".deleteDog", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Now, instead of every click anywhere in the document being inspected, only those clicks that bubble up to `#foo` are.

---

I'm guessing you originally tried to use `on` like this:

```
$(".deleteDog").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

This is functionally identical to saying:

```
$(".deleteDog").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Omitting the selector parameter like this creates a **directly-bound** event—only the elements that match the `.deleteDog` selector at the time `on` is called will be wired.

Applying a selector—like in my original code—makes it a **delegated** event—jQuery will listen for all clicks, and if they originate from an element with the class `deleteDog`, the function will fire.

Comment: hmm interesting, I have only really started with jQuery and what I have been doing is 'defining the functions' on the jQuery object before appending it to a container. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KV6QD/1/) is an example of the kind of way I would deal with what I think is similar to the kind of behaviour the OP is trying to achieve. Constructive criticism appreciated :-)

Comment: @Tom - well the remove button doesn't work, but otherwise it looks like an intelligent attempt.  Of course saying $("...").click is equivalent to using bind, so that will never work with dynamically added content, but in that particular case the add and remove buttons are static

Comment: @AdamRackis I tried replacing the delete function with what you suggested. $(".newDog").on("click", ".deleteDog", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
}); and with that I also added a class called newDog to my containing DIVs.. but it still won't work =/

Comment: @AdamRackis It's like the script doesn't recognize that the DIVs have been added.. as it works perfectly for my first DIV which has the same structure, but is "hard-coded" into the form from start

Comment: @Tom for that to work, the remove buttons would have to be in a div with the class newDog.  Just do `$(document).on("click", ".deleteDog", function() {` and see if that works.

Comment: @AdamRackis Like I said in my previous comment, I DID add a class to the containing DIV called newDog. But it still didn't work.. HOWEVER, I changed the code to $(document) like you suggested seconds ago, and it WORKED!! :D Thanks a lot! Been driving me crazy ^^ But, why didn't it work when I added class="newDog" to the containing div? :S Anyways, Thanks again!

Comment: @Tom - not sure - that should work.  The containing div exists when the page is rendered, right?  It's not dynamically added or anything, is it?  If you post an updated fiddle I can take a look at it

Comment: @Adam No, the DIVs are dynamically added. Might be that! But since $(document) works perfectly, I'll stick to that :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Tom - Then that's why it didn't work.  Whatever you put in $() has to be there when the page loads.  using document will work, like you did, or you could add a *new*, static container, named `foo`, and put all your dynamic stuff in *there*.  Then `$("#foo").on(...`  Or just stick with $(document).on - the performance difference probably won't be noticable

Comment: @AdamRackis good morning, the remove button does work you have to select the 'rows' you want to remove. I'm still seeing the same behaviour even if the whole thing is rendered after DOM ready [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/KV6QD/2/), maybe I haven't understood what you said, but I believe it is because I am creating jQuery objects before appending the to them DOM, so they are floating around the RTE :-). I think that if you are adding just html to the page similar to `.innerHTML()` you won't have a jQuery object so you use .bind() etc to create them and add events etc too

Comment: Aha seems like `.bind()` and `.on()` would be particularly useful for information loaded by via ajax :)