# Cannot set click event handler on dynamically created content

Tags: jquery

I have some code like this:

```
$('.play').on( 'click', function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

The `.play` element is dynamically created with `$('.game').html('<span class="paly">Play</span>')` method. However, I have nothing in my console log when I'm clicking on this span. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

PS: I am using jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8774734/1114171) may help, i believe you are using `on()` like `bind()` not like `on()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `live()` - it has been deprecated. Instead use `on()`, but use it on a parent element to delegate the event to, like this:

```
$('#parentOfPlay').on('click', '.play', function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

Comment: That would be the other around: `$("#parentOfPlay").on("click", ".play", function() {});`.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. If I understant right I need to use $(document).on with dynamic content an $('.selector').on with non-dynamic content, right?

Comment: Yes - although if it's dynamic content, it should be the nearest non-dynamic containing element. If you use `document` you may see a performance decrease.

Answer (score 1):

You can use live (which is now deprecated in 1.7.1 so you really shouldn't use it) or do it with on, but you where doing 'on' wrong.

```
$(document).on('click', '.play', function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good break down of what to use and when. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8845306/1139444

`.on` will give you the affect you are looking for but you need to do it on the document selector and put the class selector into the `.on` call.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.play', function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.play` selector is looking for a container with that class, so you'll need to generate the code with:

```
$('.game').html('<span class="play">Play</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` sets the contents of all blocks that have a class named game to Play. You have not created any class `.play` hence doing `$(".play")` yields nothing. The click function is not bound to anything and nothing is shown on the console. Try doing `$(".game").on("click",function(){});`

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
$(document).on('click', '.play'
    function(){
        console.log('click');
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated and must be avoided. Use `.on()` or `.delegate()`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$('.play').live( 'click', function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure the ".play" element is already there when executing your code? Or maybe it's only created later in code.. It might be an ordering issue.

edit: If you want it dynamic, use 'live' instead of 'on as suggested by others:)